# Hyper-V Manager can't connect to Windows Hyper-V Server 2012 R2 Core

Tags: windows, windows-firewall, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

A short overview:

- Server running Windows Hyper-V Server 2012 R2 Core "Adama", up to
  date
- Core is accessible via RDP Running VM with Windows Server
  Essentials 2012 "Apollo", also up to date and accessible via RDP
- Apollo functions as a File server, AD Services haven't been activated
  yet, so there is a domain, but unused, everything goes via WORKGROUP
- Client running Windows 8.1 Pro, up to date
- All via local network

My situation:

Everything used to be running well, all the mmc snap-ins were available on the client, etc, etc... The last time I used the Hyper-V Manager on the Client has been more then a month ago. Today I fired it up, wanting to add a new VM for a postgresql DB, and I'm unable to connect to the Hyper-V server with the know error "An error occurred while attempting to connect.... Check that the Virtual Machine.... authorized to connect to ...."

I've been checking anything I (and google ;)) can think of, all accounts seem to be in order via cmdkey, via mmc I can connect, but not to the Disk Management (Unable to connect to Virtual Disk Service), Device Manager. The Firewall isn't accessible anymore, but the Task Scheduler, Performance, Users, etc... are still accessible...

So in short, to me it seems to be a firewall issue, but I'm not well versed in the windows firewall and all it's possibilities, if anyone has any idea/suggestions?

Thanks & regards,

Fre

Answer (score 1):

I would try running HVRemote on the server using the appropriate command line for your scenario and see whether it resolves your issue.

Latest version and brief documentation can be obtained here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/hyper-v-remote-management-26d127c6

Comment: Oh that's a good idea! I wish I'd have thought of it sooner! ... oh wait I did :P

Comment: You're not the asker of the question, and the OP didn't state they had tried the HVRemote script already. I'd rather mention the more obvious steps and risk someone feeling patronised (not intended) than leave them without what could be helpful information.

Answer (score 0):

http://nearlydeaf.com/?p=1149

Try this - I'm having the exact same issue although mine is on a domain.

Also, check the local users on the hyperv box to see if password has expired?

Comment: I went through everything the linked guide said to no avail. I had added the credentials of the server to the client with cmdkey, now I've created two idential local accounts on the client & server with also no change.
The used account on the server was said to never expire.

Comment: Can the hyperv server resolve your clients hostname correctly? (hint try putting the hostname in to the hosts file).

Comment: are you running any AV/Firewall on your client? The hyperv has to connect back to your client PC. I just fixed my issue by disabling Symantec endpoint!! :D

Comment: and you've done the dcomcfg.exe anon access?

Comment: - resolving of hostnames works both ways (on the client the server is in the host file).
- on the client just windows defender & firewall, turning them off didn't make a difference
- Done the dcomcfg anonymous access

Comment: have you ran the HVRemote commands?  http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/hyper-v-remote-management-26d127c6  
Is your client on a domain? When you entered the cmdkey credentials on your client machine did you use the local hostname of the hyperv with the remote user? e.g. hypervsrvr\administrator

Comment: Also try connecting again and look at both event logs. I presume you can connect via MMC?

Answer (score 0):

HERE IS WHAT WORKED FOR ME:
Create an admin acct on the client and also the same acct on the Hyper-V server with same passwords. On the client, launch Hyper-V manager by holding shift and right click, then, use different credentials (the one you made earlier).